# Efficiently setting up large arrays Fortran 77

Tags: arrays, fortran, openmp

I am solving a large system of coupled nonlinear ODEs using SUNDIALs, and I have encountered performance issues. Some profiling shows that I am encountering a severe bottleneck in setting up the arrays (in Fortran 77) that define my system of equations. In particular, I need to define an array that is a nested triple do loop, with a sum performed in the inner most loop. These arrays are filled at each time step (I'm using an Implicit-differential algebraic equation solver since I my governing equations have a non-trivial coefficient matrix) and I am looking for advice/references on potential ways to speed up these calculations. I will provide a sample code displaying my problem, as well as some detail of what I've tried so far.

First, some context:

My problematic array takes the form (an entire test code will be included below)

```
  do n= 0,niv
     do l= 0,niv
        do k= 0,niv
         sumdum = 0
         do m = 1, niv     
         sumdum = sumdum+(p(-m,l)*qmat(m,k,n)+p(m,k)*qmat(-m,l,n))
         enddo
         sqmat(k,l,n) = sumdum
         enddo
     enddo
  enddo
```

where niv is the number of independent variables. niv will end up being between 100 and 300. p(m,l) and qmat(m,k,n) are (complex) arrays previously defined (see code below).

Now, let's do a  bit of benchmarking (Mac 2.5 GHz i5, gfortran, gcc v 4.8.2 x86_64). Using the OpenMP clock, I see that for niv = 100, the total test code takes 1.49s on my machine (EDIT: I've changed this time to reflect the inclusion of the O2 flag) when

```
  call omp_set_num_threads ( 1 )
```

and I compile with

```
  gfortran -fopenmp -O2 -Wl,-stack_size,0x40000000 test.f
```

Now, if I see how long it takes my code to get to the point before the sqmat arrays are filled, I find t =   0.21s, implying around 87% of the time is spent defining these arrays. This is not surprising, since there are 4*(101)^3*100 calculations for these arrays, while the next largest array has (201)^3 elements, that is it's around 100 times smaller. Also note, for niv = 150, I find that the code takes ~ 7.01s, with 90% of the time consumed by the sqmat arrays. Finally, I note that in the context of SUNDIALS and solving this system of ODEs, these matrices consume about 50% of the computation time for niv =100.

Hopefully I've defined my problem adequately, now I'll briefly discussed what I've tried to do to speed things up.

Clearly, based on what I've written above, I've turned to OpenMP. This offers some speed ups  - 2 threads gives me a factor of 1.63 speedup, while 4 threads offers just  1.02 times speedup over the 4 thread case. The way I've used OpenMP is included in my code below. I have access to a machine with many cores, so I'm interested in seeing if there's something I'm missing with the way I'm using OpenMP, that could potentially allow greater speedup. Ostensibly, there is the issue of the different sqmat components calling the same components of p(m,j) and qmat(i,j,k). I'm not sure if this would degrade performance here, nor have I found been able to figure out a way to circumvent this, so any suggestions along this front would be appreciated.

The second line of attack is taken by exploiting symmetries of p and qmat to attempt to alleviate the number of calculations in these loops. This has allowed me to cut the number of computations in half. Also, by inspection, it seems like these arrays are 'sparse', but I cannot find a structure to this sparsity - perhaps this can somehow be exploited tho.

What I have been considering lately is turning to existing fortran suites that deal with matrix multiplication (something like PBLAS), with the hope that these would compute the sqmat terms more efficiently (seeing as sqmat is a tensor product of p and q). Does anyone have any experience with PBLAS - will this offer a significant speed up versus the canonical array structure of fortran? I'm curious about this especially in the context of parallelization.

So, to conclude, my question is how to efficiently fill the components of these types of arrays. Any suggestions, or references, would be greatly appreciated.

Nick

Sample code is included below. Note, the calls to openmp, c$omp, are indented to have the code all included in one code block.

```
  program test

  implicit none

  include 'omp_lib.h'

  integer*4 iout(25), ipar, neq, niv, Mtot,ii
  parameter (Mtot = 10)
  double precision rout(10), rpar
  parameter (neq = 4*100)
  parameter (niv = neq/4)
  integer iatol, nout, jout, itask
  integer nst, kused, hused, No
  double precision t0, t1, rtol, tout, tret, tout1
  double precision y(neq), yp(neq), atol(neq), u(niv)
  data nst/3/, kused/9/, hused/2/
  integer reserr
  integer m, j, kk, l, n, l1, l2, l3, i, ll, indsum, indsum2
  integer indsum3, i4, k, k1, k2,k3, k4, k5, k6, l2p, l2pp
  integer k3a, k3b
  double precision  po, tcond, c, qout(1:niv,-niv:niv)
  double precision res(neq),res2(niv), res3(niv)
  double complex p(-niv:niv,-niv:niv), V(niv), resd2a,
 &  Vec(-niv:niv)
  double complex qmat(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv)
  double complex qmat2(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv)
  double complex sqmat(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv)
  double complex sqmat1(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv)
  double complex sqmat2(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv)
  double complex sqmat3(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv)
  double complex q(-niv:niv,-niv:niv), 
 & smat(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv)
  double complex sumdum, sum1, sum2(niv), sum3(niv), qsum,
 &  resd, resd2, sumdum2
  double complex ssum1, ssum2, forcing(niv)
  double precision seconds, seconds2, seconds3,seconds4,seconds5
  real :: start, finish
  call omp_set_num_threads ( 1 )
  seconds = omp_get_wtime ( )


  write ( *, '(a)' ) ' '
  write ( *, '(a,i8)' ) 
 &  '  Number of processors available = ', omp_get_num_procs ( )
  write ( * ,'(a,i8)' ) 
 &  '  Number of threads =              ', omp_get_max_threads ( )
  y = 0
  do i = 1, niv
  y(i) = 0.1d0*i
  enddo
  do i = niv+1,2*niv
  y(i) = -0.01d0*i
  enddo 
  c$omp parallel private(m,j,kk,l,k1,k2,k3a,k3b,k4,k5,k6) shared(p)
  c$omp do 
  do  j = -niv, niv
      do m = -niv, niv
      kk = m-j
      l = m-j
      k1 = m
      k2 = j
      k3a = m
      k3b = j
      k4 = m-j
      k5 = j
      k6 = m-j
      if (abs(kk) .gt. niv) then
      kk = 0
      else 
      kk = 1
      end if
      if (k1 .eq. 0) then
      k1 = 0
      else
      k1=1
      end if
      if (k2.eq.0) then
      k2 = 0
      else
      k2 = 1
      end if
      if (k3a .eq. 0) then
      k3a=1
      else 
      k3a=0
      end if
      if (k3b .eq. 0) then
      k3b=1
      else 
      k3b=0
      end if
      if (k4 .eq. 0) then
      k4 = 0
      else
      k4 = 1
      end if
      if (k5 .eq. 0) then
      k5=2
      else
      k5=1
      end if
      if (k6 .eq. 0) then
      k6=2
      else
      k6=1
      end if
  p(m,j)=(0.5*k5*k6*kk*abs(k4*sign(1,m-j)-k2*sign(1,j))*cmplx(k4
 & *y(abs(m-j))+1-k4,k4*y(niv+abs(m-j))*sign(1,m-j))-0.5*cmplx(k1*
 & y(abs(m))+(1-k1), k1*y(abs(m)+niv)*sign(1, m))*cmplx(k2*y(abs(j
 & ))+(1-k2),-k2*y(abs(j)+niv)*sign(1,j)))/((abs(m)+k3a)**(0.5)*(
 & k3b+abs(j)))
   enddo  
  enddo 
  c$omp end do
  c$omp end parallel 
  c$omp parallel reduction(+:qsum) private(m,j,n) shared(q)
  c$omp do 
  do j = -niv, niv
   do m = -niv, niv
    qsum = 0.0d0
    do n = 1, niv
    qsum = qsum + p(n,m)*p(-n,j)
    enddo
    q(m,j) = qsum
   enddo 
  enddo
  c$omp end do
  c$omp end parallel 
  q= 0.25d0*q


  c$omp parallel private(m,j,n,kk,k1,k2,k3a,k3b,k5,k6,l,indsum,
  c$omp& indsum2,i4,indsum3) shared(qmat)
  c$omp do  
  do m= -niv, niv
  do j= -niv, niv
  do n= -niv, niv
  kk = m-j
  k1 = m
  k2 = j
  k3a = m
  k3b = j
  k5 = m-j 
  k6 = j
  l = m-j
   if (abs(kk). gt. niv) then 
    kk = 0
   else
    kk = 1
   end if
   indsum = m-j-n
   if (indsum .eq. 0) then
   indsum = 1
   else
   indsum = 0
   end if
   indsum2 = m+j-n
   if (indsum2 .eq. 0) then
   indsum2 = 1
   else
   indsum2 = 0
   end if
   indsum3 = j+n
   if (indsum3 .eq. 0) then
   indsum3 = 1
   else
   indsum3 = 0
   end if
   i4 = m-n
   if (i4 .eq. 0) then
   i4 = 1
   else
   i4 = 0
   end if 
   if (k3a .eq. 0) then
   k3a=1
   else 
   k3a=0
   end if
   if (k3b .eq. 0) then
   k3b=1
   else 
   k3b=0
   end if
   if (k1 .eq. 0) then
   k1 = 0
   else
   k1 = 1
   end if
   if (k2 .eq. 0) then
   k2 = 0
   else
   k2 = 1
   end if
      if (k5 .eq. 0) then
      k5=2
      else
      k5=1
      end if
      if (k6 .eq. 0) then
      k6=2
      else
      k6=1
      end if
      if (l.eq.0) then
      l = 0
      else
      l = 1
      end if
   qmat(m,j,n) = (0.5*k5*k6*kk*abs(l*sign(1,m-j)-k2*sign(1,j))*
 &    cmplx(indsum,0)-0.5*indsum3*cmplx(y(abs(m))+1-k1,sign(1,
 &    m)*y(abs(m)+niv))-0.5*i4*cmplx(y(abs(j))+1-k2, -sign(1,
 &    j)*y(abs(j)+niv)))/((abs(m)+k3a)**(0.5)*(
 &    k3b+abs(j)))
  enddo 
  enddo 
  enddo 
  c$omp end do
  c$omp end parallel 


  c$omp parallel reduction(+:sumdum) private(k,l,n,m) shared(sqmat)
  c$omp do 
  do n= 0,niv
  do k= 0,niv
  do l= 0,niv
  sumdum = 0
  do m = 1, niv     
  sumdum = sumdum+(p(-m,l)*qmat(m,k,n)+p(m,k)*qmat(-m,l,n))
  enddo
  sqmat(k,l,n) = sumdum
  sqmat(-l,-k,-n) =conjg( sumdum)
  enddo
  enddo
  enddo
  c$omp end do 
  c$omp end parallel      
  c$omp parallel reduction(+:sumdum) private(k,l,n,m) shared(sqmat)
  c$omp do 
  do n= -niv, 0
  do l= 0,niv
  do k= 0,niv
  sumdum = 0
  do m = 1, niv    
  sumdum = sumdum+(p(-m,l)*qmat(m,k,n)+p(m,k)*qmat(-m,l,n))
  enddo
  sqmat(k,l,n) =sumdum
  sqmat(-l,-k,-n) = conjg(sumdum)
  enddo
  enddo
  enddo
  c$omp end do 
  c$omp end parallel 

  c$omp parallel reduction(+:sumdum) private(k,l,n,m) shared(sqmat)
  c$omp do         
  do n= -niv, 0
  do l= -niv, 0
  do k= 0, niv
  sumdum = 0
  do m = 1, niv     
  sumdum = sumdum+(p(-m,l)*qmat(m,k,n)+p(m,k)*qmat(-m,l,n))
  enddo
  sqmat(k,l,n) = sumdum
  sqmat(-l,-k,-n) = conjg(sumdum)
  enddo
  enddo
  enddo 
  c$omp end do
  c$omp end parallel 

  c$omp parallel reduction(+:sumdum) private(k,l,n,m) shared(sqmat)
  c$omp do SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC,1)
  do n= -niv, 0
  do k= -niv, 0
  do l=  0, niv      
  sumdum = 0
  do m = 1, niv    
  sumdum = sumdum+(p(-m,l)*qmat(m,k,n)+p(m,k)*qmat(-m,l,n))
  enddo
  sqmat(k,l,n) = sumdum
  sqmat(-l,-k,-n) = conjg(sumdum)
  enddo
  enddo
  enddo
  c$omp end do
  c$omp end parallel 


  sqmat = 0.25d0*sqmat   

  seconds = omp_get_wtime ( ) - seconds;
  print*, seconds
  return
  end
```

Comment: Which part of the lower code is important (the last do parallel blocks look like they are doing exactly the same)? Btw, my i5 runs this code in 10s (1 thread) down to 3s (4 threads).

Comment: They are filling out the array sqmat(i,j,k) but over different ranges of the indices. I started out by letting i, j, k run over -niv,niv  - but one can exploit symmetries of sqmat to cut down the total number of iterations in half. I'm my machine I find 1 thread = 8.6s, 2 threads is 5.9s and 4 threads is 4.09s. Which flags are you using to compile? Are you doing anything like binding threads to cores? I'm more interested in the proportion of the speed up than the actual numbers, which are actually much smaller if the -O2 flag is included, but the speeds up remain the same on my machine

Comment: I've edited the times to reflect the inclusion of the O2 flag. The times are much smaller, but the speed ups offered by multiple processors are roughly equivalent

Comment: I'm using only `gfortran -O2 -fopenmp test.f`. The problem with the stacksize can be circumvented issuing `ulimit -s unlimited`. Maybe, this could help to some degree.

Comment: Concerning my question: I didn't recognize the changed order of `l` and `k` in the loops with respect to the block before. To speed up things a bit, I tried reformulating this sum as a vector operation using strides and `SUM` to get `sqmat(k,l,n) = SUM(p(-1:-niv:-1,l)*qmat(1:niv,k,n)+p(1:niv,k)*qmat(-1:-niv:-1,l,n))` in the first loop, but I couldn't see any noticable difference. But you may give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your post, my first thought was that you should do more serious profiling. The timing information you give is very rudimentary, and there is no actual analysis of floating point operation performance or memory bandwidth usage.

Looking at what you claim to be the slowest part of the code, I can see what are essentially lots of small matrix multiplications. You're doing them as a per-element dot product, which is certainly going to be much worse that of an optimized BLAS library with efficient reuse of cache. The best way to increase performance would also be to try to write your code using only large matrix multiplications (combining certain dimensions), which will also increase the usefulness of using threaded BLAS libraries. That way you should get much better performance.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, but I've been slowly chipping away at this problem. I ended up using OpenBLAS to speed up this (tensor) matrix multiplication, and I ended up finding a near order 10 speed up in the computation. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I can't put this in a comment, but it's more a question than an answer. Your question seems to revolve a lot around the last part of the code:

```
  c$omp parallel reduction(+:sumdum) private(k,l,n,m) shared(sqmat)
  c$omp do SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC,1)
  do n= -niv, 0
  do k= -niv, 0
  do l=  0, niv      
    sumdum = 0
    do m = 1, niv    
      sumdum = sumdum+(p(-m,l)*qmat(m,k,n)+p(m,k)*qmat(-m,l,n))
    enddo
    sqmat(k,l,n) = sumdum
    sqmat(-l,-k,-n) = conjg(sumdum)
  enddo
  enddo
  enddo
  c$omp end do
  c$omp end parallel
```

The approach you take here at the parallelism is somewhat confusing. I do not see, why you need the reduction term at all, the sumdum could be a perfectly private variable, and you stated, that k,l,n are all supposed to be independent. In your code, the summation happens in the innermost loop, which is not even parallelized, except you forgot to include the collapse clause in your example code. Right now only your outermost loop gets parallelized, leaving you with 100-300 loop iterations to distribute over the threads, if I understood that correctly. Which actually should be fine for less than 10 threads, however I'd guess the reduction and the dynamic scheduling is completely killing you here.

To me it looks, like the following would still be a valid parallel implementation:

```
  !$omp parallel private(k,l,n,m,sumdum) shared(sqmat)
  !$omp do collapse(3)
  do n= -niv, 0
  do k= -niv, 0
  do l=  0, niv      
    sumdum = 0
    do m = 1, niv    
      sumdum = sumdum+(p(-m,l)*qmat(m,k,n)+p(m,k)*qmat(-m,l,n))
    enddo
    sqmat(k,l,n) = sumdum
    sqmat(-l,-k,-n) = conjg(sumdum)
  enddo
  enddo
  enddo
  !$omp end do
  !$omp end parallel
```

You could speed this further up, by manually unrolling the summation loop, and using a strip-mining approach to vectorize the summation operation.